# How can I remove duplicates in comma-separated text, ignoring the first column, keeping only unique lines?

Tags: regular-expression, microsoft-windows, replace, sort

I have a sparse CSV file with data shaped like in this simplified example. I am omitting the header, `Age,Fruit,Color,Count`, but I can include it in my file if needed. You can see that the sparse rows without a `Color` are sums of all the `Color`s of the fruit, but I don't need to treat those any differently from the other rows.

```
Old,Apple,,22
New,Apple,,51
Old,Apple,Green,8
New,Apple,Green,8
Old,Apple,Red,14
New,Apple,Red,43
Old,Banana,,3
New,Banana,,3
Old,Banana,Yellow,3
New,Banana,Yellow,3
Old,Cherry,,10
New,Cherry,,10
Old,Cherry,Black,2
New,Cherry,Black,10
Old,Cherry,Red,8
New,Cherry,Red,0
```

I know that there are exactly two lines for each fruit sum, and for each fruit-color pairing in the file, one "Old" and one "New."

How can I remove all instances of any lines that were repeated, ignoring the first column but preserving it? That is, I want to keep only these lines:

```
Old,Apple,,22
New,Apple,,51
Old,Apple,Red,14
New,Apple,Red,43
Old,Cherry,Black,2
New,Cherry,Black,10
Old,Cherry,Red,8
New,Cherry,Red,0
```

I don't need to preserve any sort order, and I can also separate the data however I want. For example, I could place all the rows with no color in one file, and all the rows with color in another.

It doesn't matter if this is a one-line sort or regex command, a sequence of separate commands, a macro, etc., and it doesn't matter if it's slow to run. Sadly, I'm using GVIM 8.2 on Windows Server 2019, so I don't have access to POSIX commands. (Vim probably isn't the ideal tool for this job, but I'm sure there's a way to pull this off and it seems like a fun puzzle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:g/^[^,]*\(,.*\)\n[^,]*\1$/.,+d
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! It leaves blank lines behind where it removed the duplicates, so with a trivial `:g/^$/d` to follow I had exactly the CSV file I needed.